# Running the same function multiple times concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrent-processing

So what I want to do is run the same function multiple times simultaneously while getting a result as return and storing it in an array or list. It goes like this:

```
def base_func(matrix,arg1,arg2):
    result = []
    for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        #perform necessary operation on row and return a certain value to store it into result
        x = func(matrix[row],arg1,arg2)
        result.append(x)
    return np.array(result)
```

I tried using threading in python. My implementation goes:

```
def base_func(matrix,arg1,arg2):
    result = []
    threads = []
    for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        t = threading.Thread(target=func,args=(matrix[row],arg1,arg2,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        res = t.join()
        result.append(res)
    return np.array(result)
```

This doesn't seem to work and just returns `None` from the threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running same function for multiple files in parallel in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889268/running-same-function-for-multiple-files-in-parallel-in-python)

Comment: The answer by @thepunitsingh seems to be correct. As just a suggestion, I think you can define `result` as a global variable and do appending into it in `func` function

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the [documentation of `threading.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join), it says:

> As join() always returns None, you must call is_alive() after join() to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the join() call timed out.

You will always get `None` from these line of your code:

```
res = t.join()
result.append(res)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) mentions a similar problem as yours, please follow this for your solution. You might want to use `concurrent.futures` module as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915138/6701627).